# Search and replace in VS2008 - linebreak

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2008

If I need to replace a text

```
<p>
this text including the paragraph needs to be replaced
</p>
```

How can I do this with VS2008 "search and replace"?

**EDIT**

One way is to use regex like suggested by Daniel. Its just pretty complicated. The real searchexpression at the end was:

```
\<div id="searchStore"\>\n[^\<]*\<[^\>]*\>\n[^\<]*\<[^\>]*\>
```

Thats to much for simple minded persons like us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the **"Use Regular Expressions"** checkbox in the Search/Replace dialog box and create a Regular Expression to match what you need.

`(<p>\r\nthis text including the paragraph needs to be replaced\r\n</p>)`

would match your example.

Comment: This worked when I changed \r\n to \n. I also had to escape brackets.At the end it turns out to be a lot of work... This is a part of VS that pretty much sucks.

Comment: Ah, of course. `\r\n` is the *nix-compatible line-break escape character. I'm glad you got it working with `\n` though - glad I managed to help. You're right though - it would be much better if the Search & Replace worked with multiple lines.